# Difference between Gitbash and Sourcetree app terminal

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to implement `ssh keys pairs` for git using bitbucket.

Then i got [**this link**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git) It is using `Gitbash` for `commandline`. Now i got confused bet the `Terminal in SourceTree UI` and `Gitbash`.
 So are they same ? If no then will using any of twos for git command make any difference ?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as long as both git shell have the same `HOME` environment variable referring to the same folder, both shells will be able to find the same ssh keys and config.

If you are on Windows, you need to make sure of what `%HOME%` is set to, because this isn't a variable set by default (it is set for instance by [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat#L9-L10), for the classic git shell).

Comment: @loop what OS are you using? What version of Git?

Comment: I am using Windows. It is the latest one.

Comment: @loop so my answer stands. Make sure HOME is defined and references the same folder. Msysgit (Git for Windows) has ssh included in its distribution.

Comment: Ok after defining Home - Will the procedure for setting ssh in the link that use Gitbash - be same on sourcetree terminal ?

Comment: @loop if the `HOME` is the same, any ssh key/config that you define in one will be found by the other shell, no need to define them twice.